# Using appendTab() and creating charts with ggplot in Shiny: charts are changing

Tags: r, shiny

This is my code:

The idea is to create panels with appendTab(), let the user create charts and after this click on a button to run some kind of model.

The idea is almost done, but I noticed that when I come back to the first panels the color of the chart is the same as the last chart.

Here I have a [GIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format) image showing that when I come back to the previous panel the color always maintain the last color (yellow).

Why?

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

colors_hex <- c("#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF", "#FFFF00", "#FF00FF")

data <- gapminder::gapminder %>% filter(country == 'Italy')


# Adiciona ruído aleatório aos valores da coluna 'pop'
desvio_maximo = 0.05  # Ajuste conforme necessário para controlar o desvio máximo
noise <- rnorm(n = nrow(data), mean = 0, sd = desvio_maximo * mean(data$pop))
pop_com_ruido <- data$pop + noise
ui <- fluidPage(

  navbarPage(
    "Rodando Modelos Econométricos com seus dados...",
    id = "tabs"
  ),
  actionButton("add_tab", "Adicione um Painel"),
  tableOutput("head"),

  uiOutput("tabs_content")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$add_tab, {
    tab_name <- paste("Gráfico e Regressão Modelo ", input$add_tab)
    appendTab(
      inputId = "tabs",
      tabPanel(tab_name,
               actionButton(inputId = str_remove_all(paste0(tab_name,'criar')," "),
                            paste0("Crie o Gráfico")),
               actionButton(inputId = str_remove_all(paste0(tab_name,'mod')," "),
                            paste0("Rode a ",tab_name)),
               plotOutput(paste0("plot",input$add_tab))
      ),
      select = TRUE
    )
      observeEvent(
        input[[str_remove_all(paste0(tab_name,'criar')," ")]],{
          output[[paste0("plot",input$add_tab)]] <- renderPlot({
          p <- ggplot(data = data,aes(x = year, y = pop)) + geom_line( color = colors_hex[input$add_tab])
          p
        }
      )


    })
      observeEvent(
        input[[str_remove_all(paste0(tab_name,'mod')," ")]],{
          output[[paste0("plot",input$add_tab)]] <- renderPlot({
            ggplot(data = data,aes(x = year, y = pop)) +
              geom_line(color = colors_hex[input$add_tab])+
              geom_line(aes(x = year, pop_com_ruido),color = 'black',size = 4)
          }
          )
        })

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use `input$add_tab` for all the color values. And since that's a reactive value, it gets recalcualted each time that value changes. It's current value isn't stored with the plot itself. In order to keep it from being reactive, you want to isolate the current value. You can do

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$add_tab, {
    new_index <- isolate(input$add_tab)
    tab_name <- paste("Gráfico e Regressão Modelo ", new_index)
    tab_color <- colors_hex[new_index]
    
    appendTab(
      inputId = "tabs",
      tabPanel(tab_name,
               actionButton(inputId = str_remove_all(paste0(tab_name,'criar')," "),
                            paste0("Crie o Gráfico")),
               actionButton(inputId = str_remove_all(paste0(tab_name,'mod')," "),
                            paste0("Rode a ",tab_name)),
               plotOutput(paste0("plot",new_index))
               
      ),
      select = TRUE
    )


    observeEvent(
      input[[str_remove_all(paste0(tab_name,'criar')," ")]],{
        output[[paste0("plot",new_index)]] <- renderPlot({
          p <- ggplot(data = data,aes(x = year, y = pop)) + 
            geom_line( color = tab_color)
          p
        })
        
      })
    
    observeEvent(
      input[[str_remove_all(paste0(tab_name,'mod')," ")]],{
        output[[paste0("plot",new_index)]] <- renderPlot({
          ggplot(data = data,aes(x = year, y = pop)) + 
            geom_line(color = tab_color)+
            geom_line(aes(x = year, pop_com_ruido),color = 'black',size = 4)
        })
      })
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

We capture the current value with `new_index <- isolate(input$add_tab)` and then use that value when creating the other reactive objects.